# Override html.tpl.php per node type does not work

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I saw that this was asked few times before, and i tried the answers, and i tried modifying the answers, yet nothing.

Case: I have advanced forums installed, and i am using appcache(don't you dear to run away now!) Obviously i need to turn appcache off when surffing forums, and i managed to make custom html.tpl.html for /forum and /forums, so when i am looking forum list and topic list i wont get cached. But then: When i am looking at forum topic, it is a post ofc, and post type (machine type is forum) and i have defined in template.php:

```
function flowrox_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
    $node = menu_get_object();

    if ($node && $node->nid) {
        $vars['theme_hook_suggestion'][] = 'html__' . $node->type;
    }
}
```

and it wont make change.

So i am able to change html.tpl.php for path but not for node type. Help me please and correct my knowledge for making such things.

Thanks for all!!! (btw i dont need a lesson of appcache, sincerely if you have manifest = x.appcache" in your html tag it will cache it, even if it's in network section)

Comment: mb clear drupal theme cache? that 'solution' helped me a couple of times sadly enough

Comment: no use ;_; tried it 5 times, and always when i do changes

Comment: in what hook are you adding the theme_hook_suggestions, could you post all theme_hook_suggestions?

Comment: edited post bump etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O M G, I feel so sorry for you now.

It should be `$vars['theme_hook_suggestions']` and not `$vars['theme_hook_suggestion']`
(the s at the end of suggestion)

Comment: these ffeelingSSS im holding right now. you cant imagine. but yea thanks million times man <3

Answer (score 4):

There is a slight difference between `$vars['theme_hook_suggestions']` and `$vars['theme_hook_suggestion']`.

**`$vars['theme_hook_suggestions']`** is an **ARRAY** of theme suggestions, and the template at the end of this array has higher priority than preceding ones.

```
// example
$vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'html__' . $node->type;
```

**`$vars['theme_hook_suggestion']`** is a **STRING** representing the template file to use and it has higher priority than `$vars['theme_hook_suggestions']`. Which means that if any theme suggestion is passed to `$vars['theme_hook_suggestion']`, `$vars['theme_hook_suggestions']` will be ignored.

```
// example
$vars['theme_hook_suggestion'] = 'html__' . $node->type;
```